# Why scaling of arrow head works only for default > and not for latex, stealth, or other types?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am following the [answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150721/adjusting-the-size-of-an-arrow) where it shows how to adjust the arrow head. It works, but only for default `>` arrow head. When I change it to `latex`, `stealth` or any of the other type of arrow heads, the size does not change.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,decorations.markings,math,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-{>[scale=1.0]}] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture} %works ok, gets larger
\draw[-{>[scale=3.0]}] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture} %does not scale, only change shape
\draw[-{latex[scale=3.0]}] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture} %does not scale, only changes shape
\draw[-{stealth[scale=3.0]}] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What would the syntax be to scale the other arrow heads? Using the above layout and not using `tikzset` or other fancy macros. Am I doing something wrong in the above?

Comment: Try with arrows.meta library. Described is in TikZ manual in chapter III. It gives more possibilities to select/design desired arrow.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Load the TikZ library `arrows.meta` and use the scalable arrows that come with that library:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc,decorations.markings,math}

\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-{>[scale=1.0]}] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture} %works ok, gets larger
\draw[-{>[scale=3.0]}] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture} %does not scale, only change shape
\draw[-{Latex[scale=3.0]}] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture} %does not scale, only changes shape
\draw[-{Stealth[scale=3.0]}] (0,0) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice to difference between `latex` vs `Latex`, and `stealth` vs `Stealth` for naming the type of arrowhead.

Comment: thanks. I have loaded the arrow.meta as you can see from my example. The problem was  in me using lower case `latex` vs. `Latex`. But then how did it work? no error and I get the arrow shape ok, but it was not scaled. This is very strange. btw, I got the names from [this site](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/contrib/tex-contrib/beamer/pgf-1.01/doc/generic/pgf/version-for-tex4ht/en/pgfmanualse24.html) which shows then using LowerCase. (at the bottom of the page). So I just used the same.