# Workaround for "dimension too large" for short, custom decorated, arcs?

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations, pgf-decorations

I have already seen [Avoiding `Dimension too large' and `ill-formatted floating point' errors in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150614/avoiding-dimension-too-large-and-ill-formatted-floating-point-errors-in-tikz), and probably there is no answer, but let's see...

I have this MWE, with a custom decoration, which can be applied to an arc, but not a short arc:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,tightpage,border=1bp]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usepackage{trace}

\pagecolor{yellow!15} % ignored with preview, but not w/ varwidth

\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd, %
  /pgf/decoration/deccrosslw/.store in=\deccrosslw, %
  /pgf/decoration/deccrosslw=0.2cm, %
  /pgf/decoration/deccrosslen/.store in=\deccrosslen, %
  /pgf/decoration/deccrosslen=1pt, %
}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{deccross}{initial}
{
  \state{initial}[width=\deccrosslen]
  {
    \pgfpointdecoratedinputsegmentlast
    \pgfgetlastxy{\dcplx}{\dcply} % grab coords in macros
    \typeout{initial \deccrosslen, \pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength, dcpl \dcplx, \dcply} % print coords to stdout
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}} % already done, but anyway
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\deccrosslen}{0pt}} % trace the actual line out (along "x" axis)
    % cross out
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.5*\deccrosslen}{0.5*\deccrosslw}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\deccrosslen}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.5*\deccrosslen}{-0.5*\deccrosslw}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\deccrosslen}{0pt}}
  }
  \state{final}
  {
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Hello:

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[]
  (0,0) -- (1,0);
\draw[decoration={deccross,deccrosslen=5pt,deccrosslw=0.5cm},decorate]
  (0,1) -- (1,1);
\draw[decoration={deccross,deccrosslen=2pt},decorate]
  (0,2) -- (1pt,2); % short - no problem

\draw[] (2,0) -- ++(0,2cm)
  arc (90:45:2cm) ;

\draw[] (4,0) -- ++(0,2cm)
  coordinate(cs)
  decorate[decoration={deccross}]{ arc (90:45:2cm) }
  coordinate(ce);

%\traceon
\draw[decoration={deccross},decorate]
  (cs)
  %arc (90:92:2cm) % ! Dimension too large. <to be read again> \relax
  arc (90:97:2cm) % 90:97 ok, 90:96 dimension too large
  ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When the code works, as in the paste above, this is what is generated:

[image: test04a]

But if the short `arc (90:92:2cm)` is uncommented, then there is a crash with `! Dimension too large.`. This is exactly referred in [Avoiding `Dimension too large' and `ill-formatted floating point' errors in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150614/avoiding-dimension-too-large-and-ill-formatted-floating-point-errors-in-tikz) :

> There is not much you can do. ... Because TeX can't handle the computations 
>   you throw at it. Because of very old but still shiny gears can't crunch 
>   anything that precise. By that I mean very tiny arc length due to your line 
>   width specification (It's too thick for such arc).

It may be that it is the same problem here, but still - I do use a line width, which is actually thin? Also, note there is no problem with a short line - only with a short arc...

I tried to `trace` a bit, and I've tried to reconstruct a "stack trace" (see selected copypaste below); it seems like there is a `\pgfmathloop` to do the decoration, where `\pgfmathveclen@` is called, which calls `\pgfmathreciprocal@`, which is what ultimately crashes.

Is there anything I could do - maybe by coding a special case in my custom decoration - to have the code not crash on short arcs?

Here is the snippet from the trace:

```
\pgfmathloop #1\repeatpgfmathloop ->\def \pgfmathcounter {1}\def \pgfmath@itera
...
#1<-\advance \pgf@xb \c@pgf@counta \pgf@yb \edef \pgf@decorate@temp {\pgf@xa \t
...
 \pgf@y -\pgf@yc \pgfmathveclen@ {\pgfmath@tonumber {\pgf@x }}{\pgfmath@tonumbe
...
...
\pgfmathveclen@ #1#2->\begingroup \pgfmath@x #1pt\relax \pgfmath@y #2pt\relax \
...
fmathreciprocal@ {\pgfmath@tonumber {\pgfmath@y }}\pgfmath@x \pgfmathresult \pg
...
#1<-\pgfmath@tonumber {\pgf@x }
#2<-\pgfmath@tonumber {\pgf@y }
...
...
\pgfmath@reciprocaltemp ->0.00006

\pgfmathreciprocal@@ #1.#2#3#4#5#6#7\pgfmath@ ->\c@pgfmath@counta #2#3#4#5#6\re
...
returnone \pgfmath@x \endgroup
#1<-0
#2<-0
#3<-0
#4<-0
#5<-0
#6<-6
#7<-0000000
...
{\count91}
{changing \count91=6}
{into \count91=166666666}
{\divide}
{changing \count91=166666666}
{into \count91=16666}
{\relax}
{\dimen107}
! Dimension too large.
<to be read again>
                   \relax
\pgfmathreciprocal@@ ...c@pgfmath@counta pt\relax
```

Answer (score 6):

Well, I wanted a workaround - here is a workaround `:)`, although I'd really love to know if there is a more proper way of doing this. This workaround produces the output below, for what would correspond to a decorated `arc (90:92:2cm)` (as expected, the short arc may be a bit hard to see, but it is there):

[image: test04b.png]

Basically, first I kept bruteforcing and increasing the radius and re-compiling, until it passed. It turns out:

- For an arc angle of 90:92, I need at least a radius of 5.4cm
- For an arc angle of 90:91, I need at least a radius of 10.5cm

So, since my original radius is 2cm, and I want to show 90:91 (thus I have to use 10.5cm radius) -- I have a magnifying scaling ratio of 10.5/2 (`\scaleNorm` in the code below, with its inverse being `\scaleInv`), if I want to support 1 degree arc. The trick is then:

- Do not scale in `\draw`, but use explicitly large radius, and correspondingly magnified decoration parameters and line width
- Then wrap the `\draw` in a `{scope}`, which will scale down, *everything* (including line widths), using `transform canvas`, back to what should be original size

Geometrically, the curvature of the arc should (and does) survive the up/down scale procedure. The only problem is to anchor the scope correctly - basically, we need a named coordinate specified beforehand, to which we will anchor (below it's `cs`, which is also used to start the arc) - and then in the `transform canvas`, we can use `shift=($(cs)-\scaleInv*(cs)$)` to re-align correctly.

Note that the below can show a decorated one-degree `arc (90:91:...)` - but it will still crash with `! Dimension too large` for a zero-degree arc `arc (90:90:...)`; which is unfortunate, as a non-decorated arc typically just doesn't draw anything, and passes silently (and to achieve that, would require extra conditional checks in the workaround).

So, just the `tikzpicture` part of the solution (since there are no changes elsewhere in respect to the MWE in OP), which implements this workaround, is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[]
  (0,0) -- (1,0);
\draw[decoration={deccross,deccrosslen=5pt,deccrosslw=0.5cm},decorate]
  (0,1) -- (1,1);
\draw[decoration={deccross,deccrosslen=2pt},decorate]
  (0,2) -- (1pt,2); % short - no problem

\draw[] (2,0) -- ++(0,2cm)
  coordinate(ics)
  arc (90:45:2cm)
  (ics)  { arc (90:97:2cm) }
  ;

\draw[] (4,0) -- ++(0,2cm)
  coordinate(cs)
  decorate[decoration={deccross}]%
  { arc (90:45:2cm) }
  coordinate(ce)
  ;

%\traceon
\pgfmathsetmacro{\scaleInv}{2/10.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\scaleNorm}{1/\scaleInv}
\typeout{NOW \scaleInv, \scaleNorm}
%\scalebox{\pgfmathresult}{% not good, way off
% doing draw[scale=0.8 in  again raises Dimension too large ...
% the scope scale (without transform shape) seemingly
%  has no influence on decorations;
% so it basically restores the failure at 90:92 (90:91 passes!)
% transform canvas transforms _everything_ - including stroke
\begin{scope}[
  at=(cs),
  anchor=center,
  % scale=\scaleInv, % may restore bad @ 90:92 - even if below uses 10.5cm radius!
  % transform shape, % no real change to decorations
  transform canvas={
    scale=\scaleInv,                % works with this, but not anchored
    shift=($(cs)-\scaleInv*(cs)$),  % this anchors ok
  },
]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\declB}{\scaleNorm*\deccrosslen}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\decwB}{\scaleNorm*\deccrosslw}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\sclw}{\scaleNorm*\pgflinewidth}
\draw[
  scale=1,
  line width=\sclw,
  decoration={deccross,deccrosslen=\declB,deccrosslw=\decwB},
  decorate
]
  (cs)
  %arc (90:92:2cm) % ! Dimension too large. <to be read again> \relax
  %arc (90:97:2cm) % 90:97 ok, 90:96 dimension too large
  %arc (90:92:5.4cm) % for >= 5.4cm, it passes for 90:92!
  arc (90:92:10.5cm) % for >= 10.5cm, it passes for 90:91!
  ;
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
```